# Stop, Disable or Pause head tracking google cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am making a google cardboard game using unity3d and google cardboard sdk. I would like to find out if the best way to disable/enable head tracking so that I can stop the game when it ends or before it starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnHeadUpdated` event

Following this code.

```
CardboardHead head;

void Start () {
    head = GameObject.Find("Head").GetComponent<CardboardHead>();
    head.OnHeadUpdated += Test_OnHeadUpdated;
}

private void Test_OnHeadUpdated(GameObject head_obj)
{
    head_obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    head_obj.transform.position = //the position when you stop cardboard;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found how to disable the head tracking on the current version of Google VR: GVR Unity SDK v1.10.0.

The way to do it is adding the *GvrHead* Script to the *GvrViewerMain* Prefab. After this you can make a simple code to access the head tracking, which is controlled by the *GvrHead* Script.

```
    GameObject.Find ("VRPlayer").GetComponent<GvrHead> ().trackRotation = false;
    GameObject.Find ("VRPlayer").GetComponent<GvrHead> ().trackPosition = false;
```

Write this code on a trigger or event, or wherever you want, to disable the head tracking.

This code find the attribute *public bool trackRotation = true;* and *public bool trackPosition = true;* on the **GvrHead** and change de bool to *false*.

To understand why this code lines enterely disable the headtracking, take a look at the **GvrHead** script.

To change back a enable the Headtracking change again the bool value of the **GvrHead** Script with the same type of code.

```
    GameObject.Find ("VRPlayer").GetComponent<GvrHead> ().trackRotation = true;
    GameObject.Find ("VRPlayer").GetComponent<GvrHead> ().trackPosition = true;
```

The Script and prefab came by deffault in the GVR Unity SDK package.

**Example**

I used it for a trigger object. When the player look right to the object, the code runs.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StopHeadTrack : MonoBehaviour, IGvrGazeResponder {
public Animator anim;

public void OnGazeEnter () {
    GameObject.Find ("VRPlayer").GetComponent<GvrHead> ().trackRotation = false;
    GameObject.Find ("VRPlayer").GetComponent<GvrHead> ().trackPosition = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tracking for both position and rotation.

```
GameObject.Find("Head").GetComponent<CardboardHead>().trackRotation = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

On September the 6th 2017, the GvrHead.cs does not exist anymore. I have been able to disable head tracking with the following code:

```
VRDevice.DisableAutoVRCameraTracking(Camera.main, true);
```

Reference page: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRDevice.DisableAutoVRCameraTracking.html

Notice it **only works in the smartphone after building it**. It does not work in the Unity Game preview, and it has other issues. I have asked about these issues here: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/716

So the long best solution is probably:

```
private void TrackPositionAndRotation (bool track){
    if (track) {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        FindObjectOfType<GvrEditorEmulator>().enabled = true;
        #endif  // UNITY_EDITOR

        #if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) && !UNITY_EDITOR
        VRDevice.DisableAutoVRCameraTracking(Camera.main, false);
        #endif  // (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) && !UNITY_EDITOR

        //cardboardHead.GetComponent<GvrHead>().trackPosition = true;
        //cardboardHead.GetComponent<GvrHead>().trackRotation = true;
    } else {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        FindObjectOfType<GvrEditorEmulator>().enabled = false;
        #endif  // UNITY_EDITOR

        #if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) && !UNITY_EDITOR
        VRDevice.DisableAutoVRCameraTracking(Camera.main, true);
        #endif  // (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) && !UNITY_EDITOR

        //cardboardHead.GetComponent<GvrHead>().trackPosition = false;
        //cardboardHead.GetComponent<GvrHead>().trackRotation = false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2017.11.29**
The above code won't work because VR has changed to XR. Check: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.InputTracking-disablePositionalTracking.html